# AKSequencer to AudioKit.renderToFile only render the first note

Tags: audiokit

I'm working with AKSequence with just one track with AKMIDISampler:

```
var instrument1 = AKMIDISampler()
mixer.connect(input: instrument1, bus: 0)
sequencer.tracks[0].setMIDIOutput(instrument1.midiIn)
```

Need to export to wav, like this:

```
let audioFile = try! AKAudioFile(forWriting: fileURL, settings: settings)
try! AudioKit.renderToFile(audioFile, seconds: seconds, prerender: {
        self.sequencer.play()
}
return fileURL
```

The Audio File resulting is just the first note long. What's wrong here ?

Comment: There is a "error" tone that is made when something isn't hooked up correctly... Are you sure the resulting file isn't playing this sound? ~example: http://szynalski.com/tone#260,v0.75

Comment: No, August. I'm using AKMIDISampler and the note sounding is the audio sample. It seems a bug. Seems to work with oscillator, but not with samples. There is an opened Issue related to this in Github: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/1385

Comment: I too am having an issue using the renderToFile() for samples..  Thanks for sharing the github issue